# What is the difference between .click(...) and .live('click', ...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/X7EAn/):

HTML:

```
<div id='button' class='enabled'>Press here</div>
<div id='log'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
    width: 65px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: red;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#button.enabled {
    color: #333;
}
#button.enabled:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#button.enabled').live('click', function() {    // (1)
    //$('#button.enabled').click(function() {          // (2)
        log('#button.enabled clicked');
    });
});
function log(str) {
    $('#log').append(str + '<br />');
    $('#button').toggleClass('enabled');
}
```

This code works as expected, i.e. `log()` is called only when `enabled` button is clicked.

But, if I replace `(1)` with `(2)`, `log()` is called also when not `enabled` button is clicked.
Why is that ?
What is the difference between `(1)` and `(2)` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) binds a `click` handler to the element.  That's the most important thing, **to the element**, so whatever **elements** the `$('#button.enabled')` selector matches *at the time it's bound*, get bound...regardless of it the selector no longer matches later.

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) checks the selector *at the time of the event* to see if it should run the handler...so changing the class *does* matter, since it no longer matches.  The [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler lives on `document` and relies on [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), so it must check the selector to see if it came from an element that it should execute the handler for.

Comment: @Misha - welcome :) hope that covers it clearly, it's definitely a point of confusion for *many* jQuery users.

Answer (score 1):

In number 2 the click function is applied to all enabled buttons at that moment.  So if a button is not enabled when the function is called it will never be enabled.

In number 1 the click function is applied when-ever needed -- that is  if there is a change to the DOM that element is checked again to see if it need to have the click function applied to it.