# Difference between .on and .live

Tags: jquery

I was wandering what is the difference between 'on' and 'live'

`$('selector').on('click', function(){
});`

`$('selector').live('click', function(){
});`

When does it make sense to use one over the other.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686543/297641

Comment: `live()` is deprecated in 1.7+, you can't use it at all in 1.9+. In versions before 1.7, you should use `delegate()` instead of live anyway. read - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Functionally `$('selector').on('click', function(){ }); == .bind` and `$(container).on('click', 'selector', function(){ }); == .live`

Comment: That's a better duplicate: [What is the difference between .click(…) and .live('click', …)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3651259/218196). `.on('click', ...)` is equivalent to `.click`in this case.

Comment: didnt realize this was asked before. sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: IMO the question that is now linked as duplicate is not a fitting duplicate, since it mostly describes why `.live` was deprecated. However, the one I linked to describes the same as me in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').on('click', function(){ });
```

will bind a click event handler to all elements selected by `selector`. Those element must exist at the time the call is made.

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){ });
```

will bind an event handler to the `document` and will catch all click events on elements that match `selector`. Those elements don't have to exist at the time the call is made. This is also called [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

You can (and should, since `.live` was removed in jQuery 1.9) also use `.on` for event delegation, but the syntax is slightly different. The equivalent to the `.live` call would be:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function(){ });
```